# Changing the color of box model elements in Google Chrome Dev tool

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I am color blind and can't differentiate very well between color of box model in Chrome Dev tools

[image]

To me it is green-blue ish in the center and kind of like orange every where else.
Is there a way to change the color to something I can see?

Comment: One suggestion try to inspect in firefox. They have grey and blue color for the same thing.

Comment: I haven't tried them myself, but here are custom color schemes for chrome like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devtools-theme-zero-dark/bomhdjeadceaggdgfoefmpeafkjhegbo

Comment: Even if you change the theme pressing f1 in Dev Tools it appears the colors of those boxes do not change. What you can do is hover over each box which will just remove the color from the rest.

Comment: Oh common Google! They say they want to change the world and help humanity yet their Dev tool doesn't work well for the color blind :)

Comment: Currently this can't be changed by users, nor will it probably ever be without a custom theme. I'm filing a bug right now to see if we can't address this color blind problem.  -- Edit: Bug filed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=614722

Comment: Do you mind hoping into the issue and taking a look at my proposed color scheme? Are you able to tell if it works better for you? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=614722#c10

Comment: @Garbee hey thanks, the ones that have an outer yellow border are the best and easiest to distinguish

Comment: Ok cool. It will be a while before anything is done here as this is a fairly major component of DevTools. Lots of visibility. Also I need to get more a11y experts in to make sure this is the right track, because we shouldn't be changing this often to experiment. But, the discussion is started. Thanks!

Comment: There was that guy on Twitter he was very involved with Chrome Dev Tools, his name was Paul Irish I think